# Not able to access data from firebase after adding privacy policy

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

I have added a Privacy Policy link to Play Console. Before that I could access data from firebase. But after this I am not able to access firebase data. What should I do? I have linked my firebase project to the google play app. I am still able to access the data locally but installing from play store is breaking my code. I have also added the correct sha1 and sha256 keys. The app can be foud here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quoala.mukund_fruits

**EDIT**
It doesnt work in release build locally too. It only runs in debug build locally.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the privacy link and try again
If it work follow these steps to add privacy policy

1-Create your own app privacy policy (For example: https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/).

2-After created, hosted in any website hosting (In my case, I hosted in GitHub Pages) and copy the privacy policy url.

3-Pasted the privacy policy url in the Google Play Console Privacy Policy section.

4-Save and wait for review.

Comment: Thanks. I did those steps. How long does it take for review? Is this a good enough privacy policy. https://quoala-inc.flycricket.io/privacy.html

Comment: Sometimes it takes hours, sometimes days
But it does not exceed 7 days